# Why did the Community user delete this question?

Tags: support, specific-question, community-user, automatic-deletion

Due to my curiosity, I've read the [help center article on community user deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) very carefully trying to figure out exactly which automatic process roomba'd this post.

This is the question that I am curious to know about why it was automatically deleted (145 days after it was posted):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366682/why-isnt-the-image-showing-up/34366760

**Is there a rule I missed that qualified it for roomba?** I'm not asking it to be undeleted because I know the question isn't very high quality, I just want to know what caused it to be deleted in the first place.

If it were deleted deliberately by users or a mod, it wouldn't have the Community user's name on it, right?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It was deleted because its author was deleted, and it scored less than 0 at the time of its author's deletion. Prior to [this past July](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote/312594#312594), all posts scoring less than 0 would be summarily deleted if their author's account was removed for any reason; since then, we've tightened up the restrictions to only delete such questions if they're closed or have no answers scoring > 0.

I've edited the question to give it a descriptive title and undeleted it.