# Why did Community delete a question that has a +3 score answer?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, answers, automatic-deletion

My answer to this question received 3 upvotes. Why did *Community* delete a question that has a positive-score answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967013/using-input-and-print-in-the-same-line-in-python-3

Comment: Dupe of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375145 I think, which appears to be fixed now.

Comment: Why are you voting to re-open this question? I did not notice the duplicate before answering, but @cigien found it, and he's exactly right, this is literally an exact duplicate.

Comment: @CodyGray I don’t think meta questions pertaining to different specific questions are exact duplicates. They’d be duplicates if they’re about the same question.

Comment: You think it is reasonable to have a separate Meta question about every single question on the main site? Duplicate status is determined by whether the questions have the exact same answer. In this case, not only the answer, but *the entire situation is identical*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The user account that asked that question was deleted by a moderator as a sockpuppet. As part of the user-account deletion process, all negatively-scored posts belonging to that account are deleted.

Originally, the score of answers was not considered when the system deleted negatively-scored questions. [In July of 2018, the system was changed to take answer scores into account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312594), due in part to a Stack Overflow moderator's [feature request from way back in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199860) and another Stack Overflow moderator's [feature request from January 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361876).

The Q&A you linked to was deleted back in 2017, which is before this system change was put into place.

I've undeleted it now, as I think the current policy is a better one and can reasonably be followed, even retroactively.