# May my question be undeleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

Maybe a long shot, since I'm the author.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74833431/use-an-os-process-like-a-bash-pipe-send-it-stdin-and-get-its-stdout

This unresolved question was deleted due to a single downvote.

It is on topic, and shows research effort. It is about an issue that currently does not appear to be resolved, and would benefit from being an open question on Stack Overflow.

There was a similar question asked here: [How to use a Port synchronously in Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76398478/how-to-use-a-port-synchronously-in-erlang?noredirect), which is actually how I found out the question has been deleted, because I wanted to link to it due to the useful information contained in the comments.

Comment: [Why did the Community user delete this question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375145/why-did-the-community-user-delete-this-question)

Comment: @ThomA this is a request for votes to undelete, not asking for an explanation about why it was deleted.

Comment: Even if we would undelete the question now, it would be deleted again on the next run of the community bot. So you also need upvotes to that question; at least one to keep it alive till a year after posting, more if you want it to survive more than a year without answer.

Comment: The post is abandoned, @AdamMillerchip . Why undelete it? What benefit is there to undelete a post with a <0 score, that has seen no changes in over 6 months and garnered less than 150 views.

Comment: The benefit is that it serves as a knowledge base / search result for people looking for similar issues, and a possible location for the answer, if/when there is one. But you're both right, I should probably use other sites for niche issues like this, no point fighting the system.

Comment: *"and a possible location for the answer"* There *is no answer* on that question though; if there were it would likely not have been deleted.

Comment: @ThomA "the post has been abandoned" is an odd argument for a post whose author is _actively trying to save it_. On Stack Exchange sites the threshold for 'abandoned' is already extremely high since answers can and do arrive _years_ after the question was asked, in many cases. But for a *single downvote vote*, this post would happily still be sitting on the site, undeleted.

Comment: Would you prefer "was abandoned for 6 months until 29 minutes ago" @TylerH ?

Comment: It has been undeleted now, consider adding a bounty to get it to survive the next run of the roomba and perhaps get it answered as well, you have sufficient rep to do so.

Comment: @ThomA Sure, if you consider any post "abandoned" for any arbitrary amount of time when someone is not actively looking at it or interacting with it.

Comment: Yes, I would consider a question that hasn't had any changes, or even comments (or bounties), for that long abandoned, @TylerH . Better than the verbiage [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) uses, which called it a "[Dead Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74833431/timeline)". I can call it a "dead question" going forward if you prefer though to be more inline with the site's perspective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The post in question is now undeleted after three undelete votes, so you can interact with it once more. It also (currently) has a score of 0, so it won't Roomba again unless it returns to a negative score.

Comment: In other words, "Yes."

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, but post length requirements being what they are...